# Making the ipad simulator smaller

Tags: xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I'm having issues viewing the iPad simulator. Is there a way to make it smaller. I have a 13" MacBook.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The iOS Simulator for both iPad and Retina have **Scale** options under **Window**. **50%** and **100%**. I believe the newest versions of the Simulator introduce **75%** as well. This is all the options you have as far as "making it smaller". I too have a 13" Macbook Pro, and this is as good as it is going to get for this screen size.

Comment: How can i make the iPad xib view smaller. It takes up my entire screen.

Comment: There is simply no way to make the screen smaller

Answer (score 19):

You can use following commands to change the size of simulator

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> for 100%
<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> for 75%
<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> for 50%
<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> for 33%
<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> for 25%

Hope this will help

Comment: +1 Better method than the above as you can resize on the fly.

Comment: perfect, that is what I was searching for (+1)

Answer (score 4):

As of Xcode 9, you can resize it to any way you want from the corner of the simulator. It will show you the **resizing cursor**

[image]

Comment: Awesome suggestion!